# Is there a way to have a Command Block ask for Player Input?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to set a Command Block that is hidden so when the player activates it by a button it'll give them an enchanted item based off their input. (the first part of a greater system)

so far I can use `/give @p iron_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:10}]}` to give an Iron Sword with a Level 10 Sharpness Enchantment.

What I want to do is alter the above command so `iron_sword`, `16` and `10` can be inputted by the player (who will have a guide), so when the player activates the command block from a button they'll be asked to input these values. however when I google search [minecraft command block player input](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=minecraft%20testfor%20xplevel&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&gws_rd=cr&ei=Tnc5VaSzEOO8mgWIy4GoCw#q=minecraft%20command%20block%20player%20input) i'm either getting "player input" as in the interface of the command block you create the commands or using `/testfor`

So how can I alter the command above so the player is asked to input the values?

NOTE: this is for 1.7.10

Comment: This can be done with /trigger in 1.8, or any 1.8 snapshot after and including 14w06a

Comment: I think there is a way, but it would be 1.8 only.

Answer (score -1):

An exemple of trigger use:

```
scoreboard objectives add question trigger
scoreboard players enable @a question
/tellraw @a ["",{"text":"Do you think it will help you ? ","color":"gold","bold":"true"},{"text":"Yes","color":"green","bold":"true","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger question set 1"}},{"text":" ","color":"none","bold":"false"},{"text":"No","color":"red","bold":"true","clickEvent":{"action":"run_command","value":"/trigger question set 2"}}]
execute @a[score_question=1] ~ ~ ~ tell @p You answered Yes
execute @a[score_question_min=2] ~ ~ ~ tell @p You answered No
```

Comment: OP said he's using 1.7.10.