# Minecraft - How do you make a command block respond to chat?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Is it possible to make a command block respond to something being said in the chat? Or even better - make it respond to a message - /msg or /tell. I want to say something in the chat and then a comparator next to the block emits a redstone signal. Is this possible?

Comment: Or possible duplicate of [Is there a way to have a Command Block ask for Player Input?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/215177/186522)

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/165471/can-i-use-the-testfor-command-to-check-for-certain-words-in-chat would be a much better dupe target

Answer (score 3):

## No.

Command blocks can't respond to arbitrary text.

For OP players you can add a custom gamerule that they can set, but that's not completely arbitrary text, only works with OP permissions and will get removed in 1.13.

You can use `tellraw` with a clickable text, that's probably the best option for you, even though it's not what you asked for. Search for `tellraw` in the Minecraft wiki, there you can see the syntax and there's a link to the JSON format.

Comment: He can use /say too inside command block. But, will appear strange text. I recommend too using tellraw

Comment: @Nathan `/say` has no JSON formatting, so you can't make clickable text with it.

Comment: Yes. I recomment too using Chat Component API in Spigot (plugins) instead of traditional vanilla :V